# How to draw bitmap over already drawn canvas

Tags: android, kotlin, canvas, bitmap, mobile-application

```kotlin
val canvas = inputSurface.lockCanvas(null)
try {
    val source = Rect(200, 200, 400, 400)
    canvas.drawBitmap(watermark, null, source, null)
   currentFrame.draw(canvas)
} finally {
    inputSurface.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas)
}
```

Here i am trying to draw bitmap(watermark) over canvas created from Surface. But bitmap(watermark) draws below the canvas created from Surface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you are first drawing the bitmap and the frame.
By switching the drawing order you should see the watermark

```
    val canvas = inputSurface.lockCanvas(null)
    try {
        //First draw the frame
        currentFrame.draw(canvas)

        val source = Rect(200, 200, 400, 400)
        //Then draw the bitmap watermark
        canvas.drawBitmap(watermark, null, source, null)
    } finally {
        inputSurface.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas)
    }
```